# How split a /tableofcontents in two or more columns?

Tags: latex, beamer, tableofcontents

I have a long index (outline) for a presentation. Obviosly my index exceeds the size of a presentation page.

Is there a way to split a /tableofcontents in two columns?. This my code to generate the index.

```
\begin{frame}{Índice}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

Comment: this should be migrated to the TEX-Forum, right!? Can everyone do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is:

```
% preamble
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{frame}{Índice}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \tableofcontents
  \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: The assumption is that you need to include at least the [`multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol)...

Comment: Note also that in this case the TOC will be broken as LaTeX sees fit. Thus breaks within a list of subsections may easily occur.

Answer (score 8):

For a better control over the break point, one could also split the toc manually

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections=1-2]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections=3-5]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```